# Function integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to perform the following function integration in Matlab

```
a=0.4;L=10;Ic=10;ra=0.2;n=2;
D11=@(x) (1-x/L).*(1-x/L)./(Ic.*(1+ra.*(1-x./(a*L))^n)^3);
d11=integral(D11,0,L)
```

Comment: Please tell us what's wrong and what I've tried to fix it.

Comment: `D11=@(x) (1-x/L).*(1-x/L)./(Ic.*(1+ra.*(1-x./(a*L)).^n).^3);`  (element-wise exponentiation i.e. full-stops added before the carats) runs without errors. Does it give you the expected answer?